# Why i can not create new connection by my new user in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

when I create new Connection by my new user this error occurs :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNCaE.png)

> Status: Failure -Test failed: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive
>   SQL level 1 ORA-02003: invalid USERENV parameter ORA-06512: at line 2

thanks for help

Comment: Do you have any logon triggers on the database ?

Comment: no, I don't have logon trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you there is not a logon trigger there? *You* may not have created one, but someone else may have. For example:

```
SQL> create user demo identified by demo;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to demo;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn demo/demo
Connected.

--
-- so far, so good, now lets create a bad trigger
--

SQL> conn system/admin
Connected.

SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger BAD_TRIGGER
  3  after logon on database
  4  begin
  5    if sys_context('USERENV','JUNK') = 'x' then
  6       null;
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

SQL> conn demo/demo
ERROR:
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.BAD_TRIGGER'
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02003: invalid USERENV parameter
ORA-06512: at "SYS.STANDARD", line 530
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

So its possible that an administrator has done this without your knowledge perhaps ?